# Function is not working in CI framework

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

Anyone understand what is the following error when using CI framework:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Error
Message: Call to a member function insert() on null**
```

Comment: you are inserting probably null to, it expects array

Comment: [Ask the question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) properly please. Include the code that generates the error.

Comment: Yes, Please try to include all the related script which is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using is in to insert.

load database before it.

$this->load->database();

just paste this line before your insert task.

Comment: Thank you that was the case